# Devstack with Linux Bridge Setup

Tags: openstack

I created a clean Ubuntu 18.04 VM in Virtualbox and want to setup devstack with Linux Bridges instead of OpenVSwitch as backends. I setup the VM with two network interfaces which each being bridged to a physical ethernet. One (enp0s8) is used for management purposes. One (enp0s3) should be the (simulated) public internet.

I followed [this](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/neutron.html#using-linux-bridge-instead-of-open-vswitch) guide at the Openstack documentation and used the following config:

```
[[local|localrc]]
HOST_IP=172.17.5.3
SERVICE_HOST=172.17.5.3
MYSQL_HOST=172.17.5.3
RABBIT_HOST=172.17.5.3
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=172.17.5.3:9292
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=secret
RABBIT_PASSWORD=secret
SERVICE_PASSWORD=secret

## Neutron options
Q_USE_SECGROUP=True
FLOATING_RANGE="172.17.4.0/24"
IPV4_ADDRS_SAFE_TO_USE="10.0.4.0/22"
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=172.17.4.200,end=172.17.4.250
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY="172.17.4.1"
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=enp0s3

# Linuxbridge provider networking configuration
Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC=True
Q_AGENT=linuxbridge
LB_PHYSICAL_INTERFACE=enp0s3
PUBLIC_PHYSICAL_NETWORK=default
LB_INTERFACE_MAPPINGS=default:enp0s3
```

This fails with the following Error:

```
++lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:634  ip -f inet a s dev enp0s3 scope global primary                                                                                                             
++lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:634  grep inet
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:634  IP_BRD=
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:636  '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:640  [[ True == \T\r\u\e ]]
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:641  ADD_OVS_PORT='sudo ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-port br-ex enp0s3'
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:644  [[ False == \T\r\u\e ]]
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:648  [[ '' != '' ]]
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:660  sudo ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-port br-ex enp0s3
ovs-vsctl: no bridge named br-ex
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:1  exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:489                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:490                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:490                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:493                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  '[' -f /tmp/tmp.UH77TYI9rG ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  rm /tmp/tmp.UH77TYI9rG
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:504                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:399               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:506                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:507                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:509                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:510                  generate-subunit 1599133116 5497 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:512                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:515                  /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/lukas/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2020-09-03-131013.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:524                  exit 1
```

What could be the problem here? If you need additional information just ask and I will provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a comment, since I can't test it, but I don't have enough reputation for commenting here. I am fairly certain this answer is indeed an answer.

The startup script executes `ovs-vsctl` although you configure Linuxbridge instead of Openvswitch. The error occurs at line 660 in a function `_move_neutron_addresses_route` in `lib/neutron-legacy`. This function is executed when OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE is set:

```
if [[ -n "$OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE" ]]; then
    _move_neutron_addresses_route "$OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE" "$PUBLIC_INTERFACE" False True "inet"
```

Unfortunately, `lib/neutron-legacy` sets OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE no matter what. Line 227:

```
OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=${OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE:-br-ex}
```

So, my fear is that even if you set OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE="" in `local.conf`, it will be set to `br-ex` and the above code will be executed.

My recommendation: Try removing or commenting out line 227 in `lib/neutron-legacy` before launching the stack.

I consider this a bug. Or I am missing something :)